# What kind of proof system have Zalta used in "Basic Concepts in Modal Logic"?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I have read that text and I'm so interested in the proof theoretic style (as also claimed by Zalta that it is used in modern approaches to modal logic) in it: That is both more mathematically rigorous than the traditional approaches (at least I think so), and also applicable for non-axiomatizable logics. Very nice I think!

Please let me know what is it called and where I can find more about it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can see : Christopher Leary, [A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA41) (2nd ed - 2015).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interested into the "algebraic" approach to logic ...

See [Abstract algebraic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebraic_logic) and [Propositional Consequence Relations and Algebraic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-algebraic/) with bibliography.

You can see also :

- H.Andréka, J.D.Monk, I.Németi (eds.), [Algebraic logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=w8zuAAAAMAAJ) (1991)
- Dov M.Gabbay & F.Guenthner (editors), [Handbook of Philosophical Logic : 2nd ed. Vol.2](https://books.google.it/books?id=OujzCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA133) (2013), Hajnal Andréka, Istvan Németi and Ildiko Sain, *Algebraic Logic*, page 133-on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check them all.